# Filling gaps in polished wood table

Tags: wooden-furniture, table, wood-filler, putty

I have a really nice polished wood table (not sure exactly what wood, sorry), which has some gaps in various places (see photos below). As we use it as a kitchen table, it's not great as all the crumbs and food bits get trapped in there, so I am looking to fill them. How you would advise I go about it? Some kind of putty or wood filler? Ideally, I'd rather not sand and have to repolish the table if it can be avoided. I'm based in the UK in case some products are only locally available.

[image: kitchen table]
[image: gap #1]
[image: gap #2]

Comment: Filling the gaps would look like crap.  Have you tried long clamps to see if you can squeeze the gaps closed?  If so, maybe putting some glue in the gaps and clamping the table would work.

Comment: Might be pricey, but I'd get a sheet of tempered glass and just cover it.

Comment: a lot of bars around here pour epoxy over the table tops, leaving a very durable and easy to clean surface that retains the character of the table surface underneath. Watch some videos about it; it's simple, messy, you need a heat gun for best results, and it takes overnight to cure.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it properly then I would take each panel apart, redimension and clean up as necessary and then reassemble.

However, if you want to continue the bodge, or cowboy repairs, that exist then there are fillers on the market that you can use - some can even be stained to get a closer match.

I would take the first option as it looks to be a beautiful table and, if you don't have the time, or skills, perhaps get a carpenter/specialist to give you a quote - you may be surprised and it could be cheaper than some of the stuff you get from I*ea etc.

Comment: I hate to say it, but the cost of quality work to rehabilitate the table should exceed the cost of a new one. I’m sure I’ve forgotten steps, but at a minimum, you’re cutting the corners apart, possibly adjusting the length of the main planks, possibly re-rabbeting the breadboard ends, then reassembling and doing finish touch up. Add material handling and contingencies and the quote will look high. Wood never stops expanding and contracting, so a putty based solution should be somewhat flexible. Maybe add a sheet of tempered glass on top?